# Flask: Failed to turn on the debug mode by configuration file

Tags: python, flask, connexion

I'm new to Flask and learning how to configure it.

I set `DEBUG = True` and checked it was set correctly (by using `print(app.config)` in app.py). However, I saw the message `Debug mode: off`. How can I turn on the debug mode using a configuration file? (Note: I have checked `flask run --debug` works.)

Commands

```
$ pip install Flask
$ pip install "connexion[sqlalchemy]"
$ pip install "flask-marshmallow[sqlalchemy]"
$ flask run  # Start Flask
<Config {'ENV': 'production', 'DEBUG': True, 'TESTING': True, ...>  # Omit other keys
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

Files

```
/
  configurations/
    default_config.py
  app.py
```

app.py

```
import connexion
import os
import pathlib
from flask.app import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

BASE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()

def create_app(config_class: str = ''):
    config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIGURATION', 'default')

    connex_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir=BASE_DIR)
    app: Flask = connex_app.app

    if config_class:
        app.config.from_object(config_class)
    else:
        app.config.from_object(f"configurations.{config_name}_config.{config_name.capitalize()}Config")
    
    print(app.config)  # Check if DEBUG is True
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)

    #### Do other things ####
    return app
```

default_config.py

```
class DefaultConfig():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://testuser:testpassword@127.0.0.1/testdb"
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
```

Comment: I find that "While it is possible to set DEBUG in your config or code, this is strongly discouraged" (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/config/#debug-mode). I plan to use `--debug` option.